# Sorting names and using JOptionPane to show output

Tags: java, joptionpane

So my code so far is this...

```
      import javax.swing.*;
        public class TestNo2{
          public static void main(String[] args){
            String[] nameNum = new String[0];
            int numberNames;
            JTextField inputName = new JTextField(5);
              JPanel nameWindow = new JPanel();
                nameWindow.add(new JLabel("How many names would you like to sort?"));
                nameWindow.add(inputName);

            int numNames = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, nameWindow
                ,"Accept and sort list of students."
                ,JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if(numNames == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){

              String numNamesS = inputName.getText();
              numberNames = Integer.parseInt(numNamesS);
              nameNum = new String[numberNames];


              for(int counterOne=0;counterOne<nameNum.length;counterOne++){
                for(int counterTwo=1;counterTwo<=nameNum.length;counterTwo++){
                  nameNum[numberNames] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null
                    ,"Enter the name of student "+counterTwo
                    ,"Name Input"
                    ,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                }   
              }      
            }           
          } 
        }
```

There's no error when I build it but when I run the program, I would only be allowed to enter one name then the error occurs.

This is the error that shows up.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at TestNo2.main(TestNo2.java:23)

Thank you for your time in reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int counterTwo=1;counterTwo<=nameNum.length;counterTwo++){
```

should be:

```
for(int counterTwo=1;counterTwo < nameNum.length;counterTwo++){
```

Because the expression `counterTwo<=nameNum.length` causes the array to exceed its bounds (*remember that actual length of array starts from zero and is **1 Less than actual length you specified**.*

So if you have an array defined like:

```
someArray[] something = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

The value of `something.length` would be `6`. But the actual length is **`5`** (Counting as: 0,1,2,3,4,5).

And why do you have two loops for just gettings names and adding to String Array? Just one is enough...

```
for(int counterOne=0;counterOne<nameNum.length;counterOne++){
    nameNum[counterOne] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null
                        ,"Enter the name of student "+(counterOne+1)
                        ,"Name Input"
                        ,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
}
```

And then sort the array `nameNum` with whatever method you plan to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although you corrected my mistake, the error is still present. the "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" still shows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check my edited answer.